# Import file & Mapping data

Tags: scrolling, data-mapping, uploading-documents

I am working an "Import file" process. 
This process involves a mapping step and I'm trying to make it as easy as possible. I would like to avoid the horizontal scroll... Do you have any example from other application that could help me?

I have an image to be more clear what i made:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Flatfile just changed over to a vertical layout in the next version of their plug & play data import component. It allows us space for messaging about our advanced features like data healing & for the user to confirm intelligent mapping or fix errors:

[image: Flatfile V2 Data Import UI]

Answer (score 1):

SalesForce has a mapping data functionality [SalesForce screenshot](https://blog.snapengage.com/custom-data-mapping-for-salesforce-and-zendesk/)

The **vertical method** is preferable since the user can scan each mapped data side by side and avoid the eye jumping from the table header to the buttom.

Pre-mapped cell ---> Mapped data